# wordpress password must be reset im told, but there is no outgoing email on server

Tags: wordpress, email, authentication

Recently i forgot my login to my wordpress installation. 
I managed to change my password threw the database and now i can login...

But after i login i get the error:

"Please enter your username or email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email. Your password must be reset. Please submit this form to reset it."

The Problem is my server cant send emails, .... so now what are my options ?
Maybe this is a feature of a plugin i installed, i have been inactive from this site for a long time.

EDIT: Plugin is login-security-solution, i will now disable it and keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Conflicting plugin called login-secutiry-solutions caused this, I removed it and now im in.